# 2 way mixed within group and between groups ANOVA on unbalanced plan vs paired T-test

Tags: r, mixed-model, experiment-design

I have a data set of race results and I would like to compare speed difference between male and female.

$H_0$: The speed difference between male and female decrease as the race distance increases.

The original dataset is structure that way

```
structure(list(id_race = c(10384L, 10384L, 10384L, 10384L, 
10384L, 10384L), year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L), dist_cat = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("[25,45)", "[45,75)", "[75,115)", 
    "[115,155)", "[155,210)", "[210,Inf]"), class = "factor"), 
    id_runner = c(41819L, 154458L, 37670L, 194949L, 6669L, 
    30031L), sexe = c("M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "F"), avg_speed = c(8.69453846857561, 8.61650045330916, 8.60986547085202, 
    8.27262044653349, 8.24749425087864, 7.84514424862768)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001c2b01a1ef0>)
```

I have created pairs of Male/Female who have run on the same year two races in different dist_cat. And I have calculated the speed difference between them. Then, I would like to compare the average difference M/F on the shortest distance category versus all other catergories

It gaves me this type of dataset.

```
structure(list(id = c("5:11051:2017", "5:339320:2015", "5:489733:2015", 
"5:592757:2015", "5:1689001:2017", "5:1689001:2019"), cat = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("[25,45)  vs  [45,75)", "[25,45)  vs  [75,115)", 
"[25,45)  vs  [115,155)", "[25,45)  vs  [155,210)", "[25,45)  vs  [210,Inf]"
), class = "factor"), dist = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("short", "long"), class = "factor"), diff = c(0.153846153846154, 
0.22999618369165, 0.25201790658137, 0.20985360540731, 0.177019146386344, 
0.140886483829759)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a different n for each comparison

```
> data %>%
+   group_by(cat, dist) %>%
+   get_summary_stats(diff, type = "mean_sd")
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   cat                    dist  variable     n  mean    sd
   <fct>                  <fct> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 [25,45)  vs  [45,75)   short diff     99229 0.22  0.09 
 2 [25,45)  vs  [45,75)   long  diff     99229 0.186 0.159
 3 [25,45)  vs  [75,115)  short diff     36770 0.225 0.082
 4 [25,45)  vs  [75,115)  long  diff     36770 0.166 0.163
 5 [25,45)  vs  [115,155) short diff      4372 0.24  0.08 
 6 [25,45)  vs  [115,155) long  diff      4372 0.172 0.192
 7 [25,45)  vs  [155,210) short diff       950 0.218 0.087
 8 [25,45)  vs  [155,210) long  diff       950 0.129 0.174
 9 [25,45)  vs  [210,Inf] short diff       774 0.246 0.074
10 [25,45)  vs  [210,Inf] long  diff       774 0.15  0.18
```

My first idea was simply do a paired T-test for each "cat" between short and long. How ever I'm wondering there are possible interaction effects and then I will have to do a 2 way mixed within group and between groups ANOVA on unbalanced plan which is way more complicated. I'm not expert in statistics and I don't want to start something that I don't understand fully.
To me, as the paired M/F are not the same person for each "cat" factor, it is better to consider 5 different experiments instead of one.

My question is : Which statistical test could help me to answer my $H_0$ minimizing the possible error?